# Android Snooze with Finish

Tags: java, android, android-intent, alarm, activity-finish

Hi I am starting to look into android development and I couldn't find a good tutorial on snooze function. Here goes my question:

I have a simple alarm clock that I'd like to implement snooze. I have a AlarmActivity pass an intent to start AlarmAlertActivity. However, I when the snooze button is pressed, I want to call finish on AlarmAlertActivity. I have the snooze method written in AlarmAlertActivity using timer. However, when the AlarmAlertActivity class is finished, the timer no longer runs.  I don't really want to do another intent to go back to AlarmActivity, because there might be multiple snoozes. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please post some code to help us understand your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You want to implement this functionality as a [`Service`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html), not as part of an `Activity`. From the docs:

> A Service is an application component representing either an application's desire to perform a longer-running operation while not interacting with the user or to supply functionality for other applications to use.

You can design your `AlarmAlertActivity` to interact with the service (starting it if necessary). The service can then broadcast a message when the snooze goes off.

It's hard to provide any specific advice because you have not provided any details about what you're doing. However, the code on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7736816/using-service-timertask-and-broadcastreceiver-to-check-for-various-updates) might provide some guidance.